# blender crashes when creating new material slot with python addon

Tags: python, materials, add-on

I am making a python addon, and I have a panel in the node editor that includes the following line:

```
    def draw(self, context):

        ...

        layout.template_preview(context.active_object.active_material)

        ...
```

As expected, this shows a material preview box in the panel. However, if i open the panel, then create a new material slot on my actrive object, blender crashes.

The crash log is as follows, in case its useful:

```
# Blender 2.81 (sub 16), Commit date: 2019-12-04 11:32, Hash f1aa4d18d49d
0  # Warning
0  # Warning
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'MATERIAL'  # Property
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()  # Operator

# backtrace
0   blender                             0x0000000105a5ade7 BLI_system_backtrace + 55
1   blender                             0x0000000105779b2a sig_handle_crash + 362
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff73b42b5d _sigtramp + 29
3   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
4   blender                             0x0000000105c4bce1 UILayout_template_preview_call + 49
5   blender                             0x0000000105b172c2 RNA_function_call + 18
6   blender                             0x0000000105ae44a4 pyrna_func_call + 2004
7   blender                             0x0000000105e725e1 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 577
8   blender                             0x0000000105f49075 call_function + 789
9   blender                             0x0000000105f45bd3 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29155
10  pydevd_frame_evaluator.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x000000011ec9e3d6 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_22pydevd_frame_evaluator_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6294
11  blender                             0x0000000105e72cbd function_code_fastcall + 253
12  blender                             0x0000000105ae5f11 bpy_class_call + 961
13  blender                             0x0000000105c4cdbb panel_draw + 123
14  blender                             0x0000000109e85762 ed_panel_draw + 674
15  blender                             0x0000000109e852d9 ED_region_panels_layout_ex + 921
16  blender                             0x0000000109e85b0a ED_region_panels + 58
17  blender                             0x0000000109e819ae ED_region_do_draw + 366
18  blender                             0x0000000105c835fb wm_draw_update + 1899
19  blender                             0x0000000105c81250 WM_main + 48
20  blender                             0x000000010577634f main + 927
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff739573d5 start + 1
```

Any ideas on why blender would be crashing when i create a new material slot whie my panel displays a material preview?

Comment: Try polling or testing for active object or active material being None.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67673/can-i-use-template-preview-in-operator-dialog